# First letter missing when reading a file

Tags: java, android, file-io

I am retrieving data from a file and for some reason i miss the first char every time.
my code.

```
public String readFile(){
String str = "Not Authenticated";
//Reading the file  
 try{
        FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput(fileName);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn); 
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[isr.read()]; //str.length()

        // Fill the Buffer with data from the file 
        try {
            isr.read(inputBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } 

        // Transform the chars to a String 
        String readString = new String(inputBuffer); 
        str = readString;


    } catch (IOException ioe)  
      {return ioe.toString();} 
    return str;
}
```

the file contains the word "True"
i get "rue"
also when i create the file the first letter cannot be a capital? if i use a capital the file is never found i am guessing the two are not related.

Comment: What is in this file? Just the characters sequence "True", or does it begin with one byte of length information?

Comment: Method `isr.read()` reads the first char.

Comment: just the word "True" it is a basic text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that file is `text` file then read it via `BufferedReader`.

```
  StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
  BufferedReader br=null;

  try{
   br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(fileName));
   String line=null;
   while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
      sb.append(line);
     }
   }catch(Exception ex){
     //
   }finally{
    if(br!=null)
      br.close();
   }
  return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    char[] inputBuffer = new char[isr.read()]; //str.length()
```

Does this not read a character out of your reader?

EDIT: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html

Comment: isr.read i thought would just give the length of the file.
what should i try instead?

Comment: Not according to: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html

Comment: @John - No, it reads from the contents of the file. If you need the length of the file, construct a `File` object from the name and then call `length()`. However, that will tell you the length in bytes, not the length in characters. Depending on the encoding, some characters may use more than one byte.

Comment: Yes i see. I do not knead to know the length but the code wants one. if i remove isr.read i get "Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer"

Answer (score 0):

isr.read() will read a single character (ie. the first character).

To get the size of the file, you can use

```
long length = new File(fileName).length()
```

See  [File.length()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) function for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use File class to find length of a file,:

```
File f=new File("c:\\new\\abc.txt");
```

`f.length();` will return size in bytes
You should also close the file opened. by `isr.close();`